# What does the RegEx (a+b)^n(c+d)^m match?

Tags: regex

I'm unsure of what this [RegEx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) matches:

```
(a+b)^n(c+d)^m
```

I know that the `+` metacharacter means "one or more times the preceding pattern". So, `a+` would match one or more `a`s whereas `a*` also includes the empty string.

But I think that in this case, the RegEx means `a or b to the nth time concatenated with c or d to the mth time`, so it'd match strings like these:

```
aaaacc (n=4, m=2)
bbbbbdddd (n=5, m=4)
aaaddddd (n=3, m=5)
bc (n=1, m=1)
aaaaaaaaaaaaccccc (n=12, m=5)
...
```

Is this correct? If it's not, can anyone provide examples of what this RegEx *does* match?

Comment: Where did you get that expression from? It doesn’t look like a dialect used by any engine, and rather like the convention employed by some computer science texts (although I’ve never seen `+` to denote “or”).

Comment: @KonradRudolph It _is_ from a computer science text (more precisely, a text from a class I'm taking in college) about regular languages

Comment: In that case the book should previously have explained the convention they used to denote regular expressions. Your attempted explanation sounds plausible, by the way.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Instead of commenting on everyone's answer being wrong because they didn't read the comments, perhaps you should be advising the OP to edit to ask the **actual question** they want answered instead. The **question** asks what this **RegEx** matches, and was answered twice. (I deleted mine because you so quickly downvoted it, BTW, which is a little rude.)

Comment: @Ken Sorry but I disagree that this is rude: this is the *purpose* of downvotes; they’re nothing personal, merely a way of signalling that an answer is wrong. And while I agree that OP should edit the question, you seem to be ignoring the purpose of comments here: to discuss unclear points and provide clarifications. As for terminology, OP isn’t wrong in using the term “regex” even though that term is more usually applied to a specific dialect for denoting regular expressions, and his usage would normally be called “a regular language”.

Comment: @Konrad: But my answer wasn't *wrong* based on the question asked here. It's only apparent if the comments are there before you start answering the question (which these were not). The question still asks about "matching these strings", BTW. You also didn't downvote the other *wrong* answer, which says essentially what mine did. However, either way, the typically *polite* way to indicate someone has misunderstood the question and therefore posted an invalid answer is to post a comment to them and give them a chance to remove or edit the answer. No matter, though.

Comment: @Ken Well the downvote is merely an incentive to “remove or edit”. In the first case the downvote is undone, and in the second the downvoter (I) gets the chance to rescind it (which is what they should do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `(a+b)^n(c+d)^m` means "`n` slots for unordered *a*'s and *b*'s followed by `m` slots for unordered *c*'s and *d*'s"

e.g. an example of `(a+b)^10(c+d)^5` would be: `aaaababbbadcccd`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like a valid regular expression given the incorrect use of ^

^ should either be inside []'s like this [^a], or at the very start of the regular expression.
+ just means 1 or more occurrence of a character.

If ^n means can be repeated n times then these would be matches:

aaaaaabccccccccd,
aaaaaabaaaaaabaaaaaabccccccccdccccccccd

Comment: It *is* valid, just not meaningful. But of course your answer ignored the previous comments probably doesn’t apply anyway. “^n” here means “n repetitions of the string”.

Comment: If that's the case then aaaaaabccccccccd would match, and so would aaaaaabaaaaaabaaaaaabccccccccdccccccccdccccccccdccccccccd

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Perl regular expressions with the 'm' option, e.g. `/(a+b)^n(c+d)^m/m`, the 
'^' will match an internal beginning of line. So...

```
/
 (a+b)    # Match one or more as followed by b
 ^n       # Match the beginning of a line followed by a literal n.
 (c+d)    # Match one or more cs followed by d
 ^m       # Match the beginning of a line followed by a literal m.
/mx
```

(a+b) and (c+d) would be available in $1 and $2.